# MDT 2013 - TaskSequenceID / KeyboardLocale not working

Tags: deployment, mdt-2013

Until now i've only had to deploy in one language, but now we're required to make deployments in both German and English.

I have read a lot over the past 2 days about how to achieve some automation with the settings fields (during WinPE) in MDT 2013 with minimal interaction. I've been trying to use "TaskSequenceID" to auto-fill the regional settings for the 2 different task sequences i have.

I have the Gather enabled at the start of each task sequence, by the way.

Here's my CustomSettings.ini from the imagebuilding task:

```
[Settings]
Priority=TaskSequenceID, Default
Properties=MyCustomProperty

[W81PRODE-001]
SkipLocaleSelection=NO
UserLocale=de-DE
UILanguage=de-DE
KeyboardLocale=de-DE

[W81PROEN-001]
SkipLocaleSelection=NO
UserLocale=en-GB
UILanguage=en-GB
KeyboardLocale=en-GB


[Default]
SkipTimeZone=NO
TimeZoneName=W. Europe Standard Time

_SMSTSORGNAME=Building %TaskSequenceID% custom base image
DoCapture=YES
OSInstall=YES

HideShell=YES
DoNotCreateExtraPartition=YES

SkipAdminPassword=YES
AdminPassword=
SkipComputerName=YES
SkipDomainMembership=YES
JoinWorkgroup=WORKGROUP

SkipProductKey=YES
OverrideProductKey=<snip>

SkipUserData=YES

SkipTaskSequence=NO
SkipApplications=YES
SkipBitLocker=YES
SkipSummary=YES
SkipRoles=YES
SkipCapture=NO
SkipFinalSummary=YES
FinishAction=SHUTDOWN
```

The above results in the German task displaying everything with no problem. But the English one always reverts to en-US keyboard layout instead of en-GB.

Some things i have noticed:

1. Making changes in the Unattend.xml makes no difference. I didn't touch this before while using MDT 2013, but i saw it suggested by some.
2. Adding the KeyboardLocale settings under [Default] or in the Bootstrap.ini results in those settings taking precedence over the [TaskSequenceID] options. I'd expect this for Bootstrap, but not for [Default]...?

I'd appreciate anyone who can spot an error here. I can provide more info if required.

Many thanks.

Comment: http://www.the-d-spot.org/wordpress/2012/07/20/how-to-use-different-settings-per-task-sequence-with-mdt-2012/ - You need to edit a file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hexcodes for the keyboardlocale. Because it takes words (en-US) or a hexcode. Not sure what the hexcode could be but definately something to look into.